# Method hiding and the "new" keyword

Tags: c#

For the life of me, I have never understood "method hiding" despite all the documentation on it.

Overriding means using the implementation in the derived class. Am I right in thinking that hiding (by using the "new" keyword") will mean that the base class definition is used? In which case, then why would you write a method in the inherited class??

In effect my 2 questions are:

1. Is hiding the opposite of overriding?
2. What does the new keyword (for hiding) do and when/where is it used? The base class? An inherited class?
3. Any useful real world examples?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your understanding is a bit off.

First of all, overriding a method means that even when the instance is cast as its base type, the new implementation will be used because there is a proper entry in the virtual method table.

When hiding the method, when the instance is cast as its base type, the base implementation will be used because there is no entry in the virtual method table.

Given the following class definitions:

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual void Say()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}

public class A : Base
{
    public new void Say()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("42");
    }
}

public class B : Base
{
    public override void Say()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Goodbye, Cruel World!");
    }
}
```

The following code would produce:

```
var a = new A();
var b = new B();
var aAsBase = a as Base;
var bAsBase = b as Base;

a.Say(); // 42
aAsBase.Say(); // Hello World!

b.Say(); // Goodbye, Cruel World!
bAsBase.Say(); // Goodbye, CruelWorld!
```

Comment: typo in line 4 of the second code snippet: `var bAsBase = b as Base; // not a`

Comment: But why use the "new" keyword at all? It functions the same with or without it in my experiments. The only difference is a compiler warning.